# Edit Powershell GUI .PS1

Tags: user-interface, powershell

I have been researching the better part of the morning and I have come across an issue, we have a Powershell file that one of the other Admins made which has a decent GUI, however he has left since it has been made and I was told that it needed to be updated. the issue is that he was using Powershell Studio which I got his copy of but it isn't loading the GUI for me to edit. is there any other ways of editing a .PS1 file with a GUI in it?

Comment: Have you tried using the "PowerShell ISE"? I use it to edit my .ps1 files all the time and it provides debugging and intellisense.

Comment: @skukx I looked at it I just wasn't sure if there was a way to "graphically" edit it, but hard coding may be the only way to go.

Comment: Sharing an example of the "GUI in it" to which you are referring might clear up exactly what you are asking.  I'm not sure I follow as your question stands.  Is the GUI in question a PowerShell dev tool GUI or a GUI that the PowerShell script in question presents at runtime?

Comment: Has your "Admin" used Powershell Studio to create the GUI? Powershell Studio can only edit GUI for scripts created in Powershell Studio.

Comment: @J0e3gan it is a GUI that the powershell script runs, just adds buttons to make it easier for our helpdesk so we don't have to teach them commands.

Comment: @JanChrbolka Yes that is what he used but he didn't enable the recovery option and he either deleted or took the .pff file with him.

Comment: @Luke In that case you won't be able to edit it in PS Studio, but there is nothing stopping you from opening it in your favourite editor and doing it by hand.

Comment: @JanChrbolka that is what I figured but I thought I would ask and see if anyone knew of any other options, Thanks